# Windows 7 thinks i am on batteries. Power Settings incorrect

Tags: windows-7, power-management

Right now my batteries are not in my laptop. I can physically see there are none. Its plugged in and i arrived to my comp to see it sleeping. I also notice the display was dim like it would be on battery. I went to power settings and saw it set to balance and checked out the settings. When Plugged in it in fact doesnt sleep. I changed this so the screen would dim on 1 min on battery 2 on plug.

What do you know. A minute later it dims.

How do i fix this?

-edit- it seems like a simple restart fixed this. I was in the middle of a run and the app supports no resume so i put it on hibernate. It was getting annoying coming back to find the machine asleep instead of running a job. So, i think restart is a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing the settings for when the power setting is on battery and seeing if that changes anything?  Also what does your task bar symbol show?